# Get current figure size in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, size, figure

Simple question: How do you get the current figure size in MATLAB?

Example:

```
figure(1)
[width, height] = ****some function I'm not aware of****
```

Googling this always returns how to ***change*** the window size but not how to just get the current window size.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The methods you found use `set`... just use `get` instead. `h = get(gcf, 'Position');`, then look at the last two elements.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
pos = get(gcf, 'Position'); %// gives x left, y bottom, width, height
width = pos(3);
height = pos(4);
```

Comment: @rayryeng Hahaha. Easy one

Comment: So was I but I wasted time looking for a duplicate first!

Comment: I spent 3 minutes looking for a duplicate... I thought there would be one, but there isn't. *shakes fist*

Comment: @IKavanagh And I also stole an accepted answer from you today... sorry about that :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I know :( but I learnt 2 new things from you today with that answer so its all good. The obvious Java stuff but the clearly cooler <kbd> tag!

Comment: Thanks, sorry it was a very simple question.

Comment: @Darcy - Even the simplest questions help us in the long run.  We are surprised that we couldn't find a duplicate.  We're very glad you established that precedent now!